# Xcode - compiling .tcc files

Tags: c++, xcode

We are taking over a legacy project and I cannot get it to compile, the .TCC files from a taglib toolkit are throwing all kinds of exceptions.  I am using C++98 and libstdc as that fixed a bunch of issues on other projects they gave us.  I've set the file to be a C++ source file in xcode, it had it as plain text in the properties so I changed it. I'm guessing the file type is somehow throwing off Xcode or there are some changes I need to make but do not know what, any ideas?

some errors include:

/src/ofxSoundTagReader/libs/taglib/toolkit/tlist.tcc:78:9: Delete called on 'const TagLib::FileRef::FileTypeResolver' that is abstract but has non-virtual destructor
/src/ofxSoundTagReader/libs/taglib/toolkit/tlist.tcc:41:32: Expected class name
/src/ofxSoundTagReader/libs/taglib/toolkit/tlist.tcc:51:27: Explicit specialization of non-template class 'List'
/src/ofxSoundTagReader/libs/taglib/toolkit/tlist.tcc:51:36: Definition or redeclaration of 'ListPrivate' cannot name the global scope
/src/ofxSoundTagReader/libs/taglib/toolkit/tlist.tcc:50:1: Extraneous template parameter list in template specialization or out-of-line template definition
/src/ofxSoundTagReader/libs/taglib/toolkit/tlist.tcc:51:36: Variable 'ListPrivate' declared as a template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"tlist.tcc" contains the implementation of the template class defined in "tlist.h", and you're *not* supposed to compile it separately.
It's `#include`d at the end of "tlist.h", which only contains the class definition.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I am compiling the entire project, this is in the tlist.h file and the only errors I am getting are from the two .tcc files:

`// Since GCC doesn't support the "export" keyword, we have to include the'
'// implementation.`

`#include "tlist.tcc"`


`#endif`

Comment: @fizgig I mean that you're not supposed to set .tcc files to "C++ source file" since that will cause XCode to attempt to compile it, which it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have just stumbled upon this question, as I got that error myself.

The thing is, even setting the TCC files to "Plain Text" mode - does not help. Xcode tries to compile them separately for some reason.

So the solution was to uncheck those files from the "target". So it does not try to compile them as sources.

Do not worry, the header files do reference those, and they will be compiled as headers, where they will not produce errors as they complete each other...